# xcodebuild arguments in pre-action script

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to utilize the `xcodebuild` command line arguments in the bash script run in `pre-action` for a specific scheme?

i.e. `xcodebuild -scheme Debug ... -COOL_FEATURES=1`

Then in the `pre-action` script something along these lines:

```
if [[ "$COOL_FEATURES" ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Maybe it would if you'd use the correct syntax. The syntax to define a build setting is `BUILD_SETTING=VALUE`, that is without a minus. If you use a minus, you are setting a user default `-USER_DEFAULT=VALUE`, that is you are overriding a value in `NSUserDefault` that would normally come from a plist file for the process started. See also man page of `xcodebuild`. And build setting does not only refer to predefined ones, of course, you can define your own build settings and these should be exported to pre-action scripts.